# Is $\sqrt{x}$ Lipschitz continuous on $(0,\infty)$?

Tags: continuity, lipschitz-functions

Is $\sqrt{x}$ Lipschitz continuous on $(0,\infty)$?

I wonder that because I know it is on $[a,\infty)$ for all $a>0$.

Comment: have you tried to prove your claim?

Comment: I just figured that for $a>0$ the lipschitz constant $K$ depends on $a$, so I think I can do the limit when a approaches to zero, then K approaches to infinity, but I'm not sure

Comment: @José: your thinking is correct. Take a Lipschitz constant K, and use MVT to get a contradiction.

Comment: According to MVT, for a *differentiable* function, "Lipschitz" means "bounded derivative".  The interest in Lipschitz is: certain properties of differentiable functions can be proved even for non-differentiable (but Lipschitz) functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If it were, then there would be a constant $K > 0$ such that $|\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y}| \le K|x - y|$ for all $x,y\in (0,\infty)$. Then for $0 < y < x < \infty$, $$\frac{\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y}}{x - y} \le K$$

or

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}} \le K\qquad (0 < y < x < \infty).$$

It follows that

$$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} \le K$$

for all $x > 0$. Taking $x = 1/(16K^2)$ results in the inequality $2K \le K$, a contradiction.

Comment: How do you go from $(\sqrt x - \sqrt y) / (x-y) \le K$ to $\sqrt x + \sqrt y \le K$? Did you misapply the rule $(a-b)(a+b) = a^2-b^2$?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi It's edited now.